# Windows + Tomato - Client 2 Client logic = help please

Tags: windows, router, vpn, openvpn, tomato

Background: Client wants a (seemingly simple) VPN solution to connect his main-office(site A) to his satellite-office(site B)(in same city)

Never attempted OpenVPN. Purchased 2 ASUS RT-N66 routers for both sites, flashed Tomato 1.28 by Shibby VPN on each. Both have their respective WANs passed through.

site A has 1 desktop (office) Windows 8.1 - Network 10.1.10.0 - Mask 255.255.255.0
site B has 1 desktop (satellite) Windows 7 Pro - Network 192.168.2.0 - Mask 255.255.255.0
all that's required is for desktop-a to connect to desktop-b, and desktop-b to connect to desktop-a  (what I understand as Client to Client)

Both sites have dynamic IP addresses. I've configured DDNS through dyn.com and that part seems to be working/updating for both sites.
Time is set on each router

---

What I've done:
installed OpenVPN 2.3.10 on both PCs
with easy-rsa utility generated keys, i.e. init-config, vars, clean-all, and the builds(ca, client, server and dh) on/via both PCs

---

This is where following multiple guides has gotten my logic screwed up, and I'm hoping an explanation can get me back in the right direction...

Site A has a Tomato Router and desktop (office)
I config'd a common name of office for desktop client and server for the tomato router
Site B has a Tomato Router and desktop (satellite)
I config'd a common name of satellite for desktop client and server for the tomato router

In each tomato router:
I have (under VPN Tunneling:Server-Basic), Started with WAN, Interface TUN, Protocol UDP, Port 1194, Firewall Automatic, Authorization TLS, Extra HMAC disabled, VPN subnet 10.8.0.0 and mask 255.255.255.0

Site A(under VPN Tunneling:Server-Advanced) I have Client to Client checked, and put in details:
cn=satellite, 192.168.2.0, 255.255.255.0, push=checked 
Site B(under VPN Tunneling:Server-Advanced) I have Client to Client checked, and put in details:
cn=office, 10.1.10.0, 255.255.255.0, push=checked

Site A(under VPN Tunneling:Server-Keys) I put the ca.crt, server.crt, server.key and dh1024.pem I generated from Site A desktop (office)
Site B(under VPN Tunneling:Server-Keys) I put the ca.crt, server.crt, server.key and dh1024.pem I generated from Site B desktop (satellite)

Site A(under VPN Tunneling:Client-Basic) Started with WAN, Interface TUN, Protocol UDP, Server/Address Port XXsatellite.dynalias.com 1194, Firewall Auto, Auth TLS, Extra HMAC disabled, Create NAT unchecked

Site B(under VPN Tunneling:Client-Basic) Started with WAN, Interface TUN, Protocol UDP, Server/Address Port XXoffice.dynalias.com 1194, Firewall Auto, Auth TLS, Extra HMAC disabled, Create NAT unchecked

Site A(under VPN Tunneling:Client-Keys) I opened, copied, pasted the keys for the respective fields with notepad for satellite client
Site B(under VPN Tunneling:Client-Keys) I opened, copied, pasted the keys for the respective fields with notepad for office client

---

Now, to the OpenVPNGUI.exe running on each client (office, and satellite)
I used the sample client.ovpn file and set: ca.crt, office(or satellite).crt, office(or satellite).key paths to the same folder i.e. config
I set the remote path of Site A's client(office) as XXsatellite.dynalias.com
I set the remote path of Site B's client(satellite) as XXoffice.dynalias.com
I tried to keep the other settings as default(simplistic) as I could, based on what I've researched/read
after struggling and driving back and forth, I set Windows Firewall Inbound/Outbound rules to allow UDP 1194, and then Port forward on each router for: On UDP 1194 in, 1194 out, to (static private IP of office and satellite desktop PC respective to each router)

---

It's not working, I'm afraid I've got some fundamental things wrong.
Here are some questions I have that I can't figure out:

Do I have the client keys mixed up on each Tomato router? Do I even need to set those there(within VPN Tunneling option of Tomato router)? If not, how else does Router A(openvpn server) know to connect to Router B(other openvpn server)?

Do I have the remote set wrong in each client.ovpn file? It makes sense to me that site A remote should be Site B and vice versa

Does server.ovpn(and server keys) need to be in the config folder(with client.ovpn)? Or does it not matter if/since keys are put into Tomato Web Gui?

Does TAP/TUN matter when using DDNS? looking for reliability not security?

There might be more I'm missing, I'm doing this all from memory as I asked to setup Remote login to both PCs(networks) in question and was forbade. I believe in ethics, so I'm respecting their wishes, but I really need help, and 3+days in I'm getting desperate.
I've looked at the OpenVPN blogs and community forums

UPDATE--
Used this guide: http://blog.qnology.com/2013/02/tutorial-30-minutes-or-less-site-to.html
SSH'd into router, used Linux based commands to generate keys, put server keys on USB stick in Server router(Site A), copied contents for Client Router (Site B) onto another USB stick and took with me to site B.
Note- Site A VPN service started and seemed fine- though wasn't connecting to B because it wasn't setup yet.

Got to Site B, pasted contents into VPN Tunneling -> Client -> Keys, started, and after a few moments the Router crashed(or so I thought). Lost Internet connectivity on Ethernet connected and Wireless connected machines. Lost connectivity to Router via Web GUI, Putty and WinSCP.

I rebooted Router at Site B via Power Switch, and still unresponsive. I pulled WAN Ethernet from Router and after a moment could connect to Router again. I cleared NVRAM(thourough), and started over.

Same thing happened. I've heard about the 32KB NVRAM issue with the ASUS RT-N66U router, but had upgraded original firmware to the 64KB before Tomatoing. Pulled WAN again, Router became responsive.

I SSH'd into and did a top and nvram show. Load was fine, had more than half of NVRAM available(and yes, was showing a sum of near 64). Plugged in WAN, and hit up arrow and Enter to continue to monitor stats before everything froze up.

I thought 'maybe it's the keys', 'maybe they're corrupt, or there's some line feed carriage return issue'(and I'm not 100% sure there's not), but when I edited the keys and removed parts, the VPN service just wouldn't start and Router and Internet never broke.

So I moved the keys from being pasted into Keys section of WebGUI VPN Tunneling ->Client ->Keys to the JFFS(enabled and formatted first) via SCP, then put those  certs and key paths into the VPN Tunneling ->Client ->Advanced ->Custom. Same behavior. I looked at the log files, copied and brought with me home:

```
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter user.info kernel: tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter user.info kernel: tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2338]: OpenVPN 2.3.7 mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Oct  9 2015
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2338]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.09
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter daemon.warn openvpn[2340]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Socket Buffers: R=[112640->131072] S=[112640->131072]
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[1903]: System time change detected.
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Jan 28 18:17:18 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]73.XX.XX.35:1194
Jan 28 18:17:19 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]73.XX.XX.35:1194, sid=7aa2cb6f 8441e929
Jan 28 18:17:19 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=VA, L=Henrico, O=XX, OU=StaplesMill, CN=Production, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=XX@gmail.com
Jan 28 18:17:19 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=VA, L=Henrico, O=XX, OU=StaplesMill, CN=OpenVPNServer, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=XXrva@gmail.com
Jan 28 18:17:19 SiteBRouter user.notice root: vpnrouting: clean-up
Jan 28 18:17:20 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jan 28 18:17:20 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jan 28 18:17:20 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jan 28 18:17:20 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jan 28 18:17:20 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 1024 bit RSA
Jan 28 18:17:20 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: [OpenVPNServer] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]73.XX.XX.35:1194
Jan 28 18:17:21 SiteBRouter cron.err crond[567]: time disparity of 24233712 minutes detected
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: SENT CONTROL [OpenVPNServer]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0,route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0,topology net30,ping 15,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: TUN/TAP device tun11 opened
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/ifconfig tun11 10.8.0.6 pointopoint 10.8.0.5 mtu 1500
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/route add -net 10.1.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.5
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.5
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/route add -net 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.5
Jan 28 18:17:22 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jan 28 18:18:52 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: [OpenVPNServer] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Jan 28 18:18:52 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Jan 28 18:18:52 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Jan 28 18:18:54 SiteBRouter daemon.warn openvpn[2340]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Jan 28 18:18:54 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Socket Buffers: R=[112640->131072] S=[112640->131072]
Jan 28 18:19:00 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[1903]: No response to 5 echo-requests
Jan 28 18:19:00 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[1903]: Serial link appears to be disconnected.
Jan 28 18:19:00 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[1903]: Connect time 2.0 minutes.
Jan 28 18:19:00 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[1903]: Sent 7697 bytes, received 9004 bytes.
Jan 28 18:19:04 SiteBRouter daemon.err openvpn[2340]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: XXproductionXXcom: Name or service not known
Jan 28 18:19:04 SiteBRouter daemon.err openvpn[2340]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: XXproductionXXcom: Name or service not known
Jan 28 18:19:06 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[1903]: Connection terminated.
Jan 28 18:19:06 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[1903]: Modem hangup
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.err openvpn[2340]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: XXproductionXXcom: Name or service not known
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter user.info redial[1904]: WAN down. Reconnecting...
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[1985]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter user.debug init[1]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: started, version 2.73 cachesize 1500
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect no-inotify
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: asynchronous logging enabled, queue limit is 5 messages
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2457]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.10 -- 192.168.2.51, lease time 1d
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: reading /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: using nameserver 71.XX.XX.12#53
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: using nameserver 71.XX.XX.12#53
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: read /etc/dnsmasq/hosts/hosts - 3 addresses
Jan 28 18:19:09 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2457]: read /etc/dnsmasq/dhcp/dhcp-hosts
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[1903]: Terminating on signal 15
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[1903]: Exit.
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: RESOLVE: signal received during DNS resolution attempt
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/route del -net 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/route del -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/route del -net 10.1.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: /sbin/ifconfig tun11 0.0.0.0
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter daemon.notice openvpn[2340]: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter user.warn kernel: vlan2: Setting MAC address to  xx xx xx c1 a9 49.
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:19:10 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:19:11 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2551]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
Jan 28 18:19:11 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2551]: RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.10 compiled against pppd 2.4.5
Jan 28 18:19:11 SiteBRouter user.info redial[2553]: Started. Time: 10
Jan 28 18:19:11 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2552]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan 28 18:19:15 SiteBRouter user.notice root: vpnrouting: clean-up
Jan 28 18:19:16 SiteBRouter daemon.warn dnsmasq[2457]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.dnsmasq, will retry
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter user.info redial[2553]: WAN down. Reconnecting...
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2457]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter user.debug init[1]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2619]: started, version 2.73 cachesize 1500
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2619]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect no-inotify
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2619]: asynchronous logging enabled, queue limit is 5 messages
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2619]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.10 -- 192.168.2.51, lease time 1d
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.warn dnsmasq[2619]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.dnsmasq, will retry
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2619]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2619]: read /etc/dnsmasq/hosts/hosts - 3 addresses
Jan 28 18:19:31 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2619]: read /etc/dnsmasq/dhcp/dhcp-hosts
Jan 28 18:19:37 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:19:37 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:19:37 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:19:37 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:19:37 SiteBRouter user.warn kernel: vlan2: Setting MAC address to  xx xx xx a9 49.
Jan 28 18:19:37 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:19:37 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:19:38 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2674]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
Jan 28 18:19:38 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2674]: RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.10 compiled against pppd 2.4.5
Jan 28 18:19:38 SiteBRouter user.info redial[2676]: Started. Time: 10
Jan 28 18:19:38 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2675]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter user.info redial[2676]: WAN down. Reconnecting...
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2619]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter user.debug init[1]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2684]: started, version 2.73 cachesize 1500
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2684]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect no-inotify
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2684]: asynchronous logging enabled, queue limit is 5 messages
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2684]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.10 -- 192.168.2.51, lease time 1d
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.warn dnsmasq[2684]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.dnsmasq, will retry
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2684]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2684]: read /etc/dnsmasq/hosts/hosts - 3 addresses
Jan 28 18:19:58 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2684]: read /etc/dnsmasq/dhcp/dhcp-hosts
Jan 28 18:20:04 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:20:04 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:20:04 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:20:04 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:20:04 SiteBRouter user.warn kernel: vlan2: Setting MAC address to  xx xx xx a9 49.
Jan 28 18:20:04 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:20:04 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:20:05 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2740]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
Jan 28 18:20:05 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2740]: RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.10 compiled against pppd 2.4.5
Jan 28 18:20:05 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2741]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan 28 18:20:05 SiteBRouter user.info redial[2742]: Started. Time: 10
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter user.info redial[2742]: WAN down. Reconnecting...
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2684]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter user.debug init[1]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: started, version 2.73 cachesize 1500
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect no-inotify
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: asynchronous logging enabled, queue limit is 5 messages
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2750]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.10 -- 192.168.2.51, lease time 1d
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.warn dnsmasq[2750]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.dnsmasq, will retry
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: read /etc/dnsmasq/hosts/hosts - 3 addresses
Jan 28 18:20:25 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2750]: read /etc/dnsmasq/dhcp/dhcp-hosts
Jan 28 18:20:31 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:20:31 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:20:31 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from vlan interface
Jan 28 18:20:31 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: del 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address from master interface
Jan 28 18:20:31 SiteBRouter user.warn kernel: vlan2: Setting MAC address to  xx xx xx c1 a9 49.
Jan 28 18:20:31 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:20:31 SiteBRouter user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Jan 28 18:20:32 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2814]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
Jan 28 18:20:32 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2814]: RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.10 compiled against pppd 2.4.5
Jan 28 18:20:32 SiteBRouter user.info redial[2816]: Started. Time: 10
Jan 28 18:20:32 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan 28 18:20:47 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2815]: PPP session is 6635 (0x19eb)
Jan 28 18:20:47 SiteBRouter daemon.warn pppd[2815]: Connected to 00:90:1a:41:65:93 via interface vlan2
Jan 28 18:20:47 SiteBRouter daemon.info pppd[2815]: Using interface ppp0
Jan 28 18:20:47 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: Connect: ppp0 <--> vlan2
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: PAP authentication succeeded
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: peer from calling number XX:XX:XX:41:65:93 authorized
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: local  IP address 72.XX.XX.161
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: remote IP address 10.22.119.1
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: primary   DNS address 71.XX.XX.0.12
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.notice pppd[2815]: secondary DNS address 71.XX.XX.0.12
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter user.debug ip-up[2822]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: reading /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: using nameserver 71.XX.XX.0.12#53
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: using nameserver 71.XX.XX.12#53
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter user.debug init[1]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2750]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: started, version 2.73 cachesize 1500
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect no-inotify
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: asynchronous logging enabled, queue limit is 5 messages
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2825]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.10 -- 192.168.2.51, lease time 1d
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: reading /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: using nameserver 71.XX.XX.12#53
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: using nameserver 71.XX.XX.12#53
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq[2825]: read /etc/dnsmasq/hosts/hosts - 3 addresses
Jan 28 18:20:48 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2825]: read /etc/dnsmasq/dhcp/dhcp-hosts
Jan 28 18:20:51 SiteBRouter user.info kernel: tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
Jan 28 18:20:51 SiteBRouter user.info kernel: tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
Jan 28 18:20:51 SiteBRouter daemon.err openvpn[3097]: Options error: You must define CA file (--ca) or CA path (--capath)
Jan 28 18:20:51 SiteBRouter daemon.warn openvpn[3097]: Use --help for more information.
Jan 28 18:20:52 SiteBRouter user.notice root: vpnrouting: clean-up
Jan 28 18:28:06 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2825]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.2.45 xx:xx:xx:22:58:f9 
Jan 28 18:28:06 SiteBRouter daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2825]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.2.45 xx:xx:xx:22:58:f9 SATELLITE
```

I see a couple things in there I'm not sure about:

1. I see the DDNS address not being resolved XXproductionXXcom
2. I see the private IP addressing scheme of the office production site 10.1.10.0 from behind this 192.168.2.0, which tells me a connection is being made.
3. I later see WAN down, is that when things go crashy?

Unless it's something I did wrong in the configuration, here's one more thing that may be contributing:

Client Site B has DSL, and it's not good. I did a speed test and got about 2.5 Mbps down and between .25 and .70 Mbps up. Could it be that the Internet is so bad that the VPN is using every morsel of bandwidth/throughput and clobbering itself? If so, is there a way to throttle it, or scale it down so that it continues to function steadily albeit slowly?

I welcome all thoughts and hypothesis before I take another swing at it tomorrow.